# percentage not shown in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I am plotting a bar graph with amcharts and I wanted to display the percentage on the top of the bar.So below is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://daturl",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "GET",
    dataformat: "JSON",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var amc = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
        {
            "type": "serial",
            "dataProvider": data,
            "categoryField": "name",
            "startDuration": 1,
            "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start"
            },
            "trendLines": [],
            "graphs": [
                {
                    "valueField": "count",
                    "fillColors": "#0095cc",
                    "type": "column",
                    "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "id": "AmGraph-1",
                    "title": "graph",
                    "labelText": " ",

                    //the percentage calculation function
                    "labelFunction": function (item, data) {
                        var total = 0;
                        console.log(data.length + " is the size of the data in long trips");

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            total += data[i][item.graph.valueField];
                        }

                        var percent = Math.round((item.values.value / total) * 1000) / 10;
                        return percent + "%";
                    }
                }],
            "guides": [],
            "valueAxes": [
                {
                    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                    "title": "Count",
                    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    "gridAlpha": 0.2
                }
            ],
            "categoryAxis": {
                "title": "Zone",
                "gridPosition": "start",
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "tickPosition": "start",
                "tickLength": 20,
                "labelRotation": 24
            },
            "gridAboveGraphs": true,
            "allLabels": [],
            "balloon": {},
            "legend": {
                "enabled": true,
                "useGraphSettings": true
            },
            "titles": [
                {
                    "id": "Title-1",
                    "size": 15,
                    "text": "graph"
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error while plotting down graph ");
    }
});
```

So when I run the code the graphs are plotting but the percentages are not shown.Instead they show as `NaN`. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `labelFunction` wrong. You can see in the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelFunction), that the parameters given are a reference to `GraphDataItem` and the formatted label text.

In your for-loop you actually do `total += "   "[0]["value"]` which results in `total += undefined` and cause `total` to be `NaN`. That's where to wrong labels come from.

You could access the full dataSet via `item.graph.data` and make a correct calculation with this.

My suggestion though would be, that you move that for-loop to another place in your script. You basically just sum up the data values over and over again, whenever the graph is drawn. This means this loop runs several hundred to thousand times when you are just resizing the graph. You could just calculate the total sum once and use it in the labelFunction.